# Importing CSV file can't fill cells

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I am trying to import a csv file. I have the file loading but cant get the file to load the cell data into the model.

Here is my model with the import method. It should make an instance for each row and fill that instance with the attributes from each row. I see it importing the fie but not filling in any of the data from each row.

> ```
> class Report < ActiveRecord::Base        
> attr_accessor :contract,:start_time, :end_time, :source, :price
> require 'csv'
>
> def self.import(file)
>   CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
>     report_hash = row.to_hash # exclude the price field
>     report = Report.where(id: report_hash["id"])
>
>     if report.count == 1
>       report.first.update_attributes(report_hash)
>     else
>       Report.create!(report_hash)
>     end 
>   end 
> end
> ```

This is some of the cell content

```
contract,start_time,end_time,source,price
Corn,11-03-2014,11-16-2014,cme, 3.82
```

When I load the file i get this...

```
#<Report id: 380, created_at: "2016-02-04 03:41:50", updated_at: "2016-02-04 03:41:50", contract: nil, source: nil, price: nil, start_time: nil, end_time: nil>
```

Everything is nil other than created_at and updated_at what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the value of `report_hash` when running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in the line

```
    attr_accessor :contract,:start_time, :end_time, :source, :price
```

I believe this interfere with the magic that ActiveRecord generates and it seems to me that the `attr_accessor` overwrites AR and makes setting any of the fields not possible.

Remove this line and your code will work!